# Short documentary about spacesuit seamstresses

Tags: nasa, spacesuits, video

I'm trying to find a short documentary video about people who sew together NASA spacesuits.

I saw it quite some time ago -- at least 20 years, maybe longer.  Quite possibly on PBS, maybe the Spokane affiliate.  Somewhere between 5 and 30 minutes long.

The subject -- four (I think?) little old ladies who were manually sewing together NASA spacesuits (for, I believe, Space Shuttle usage) was very endearing and I think I'd quite enjoy seeing it again, if possible.

Comment: Can confirm this exists. Don't think I have a copy, though. Looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is it. It's part of a fabulous 6 Part series on Apollo called Moon Machines. Other parts covered the computer, the lunar module etc. I think this series is the best documentary I've seen about Apollo.

Comment: Like they say, it was "another time". Today [jabbing a subordinate with a pin](https://youtu.be/fJbztthNrVQ?t=887) to teach them a lesson might not be considered a good workplace practice. (somebody else could have put it there)

Comment: Thanks!  A very enjoyable watch.